# How can I measure a reaction time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a web game using Ruby on rails. A text or an image appears and the player has to take it or not, and I neeed to measure his reaction time precisely (in milliseconds).

I can't start the timer in the controller method because of the delay between the server and the player.

Is there a way to start the timer when the page has finished loading ? Or is there an other way to do ? I haven't found any solutions..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript land - save `performance.now()` in `body onLoad` or similar (`$(function(){ ... })` if you're using jQuery),
For an image - take first measurement in its onload event, because image may be loaded and shown later than just text. Also take into account custom fonts loading that may also delay rendering.

Then on user reaction take second value, difference between these will be in milliseconds.